SMS received broadcast not working (not getting called when app no longer available in recent list)
<receiver android:name=".Receiver.Sms_Receiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
Sms_Receiver.class
public class Sms_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver { @Override public void onReceive(Context var1, Intent var2) { if (var2.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) { } } }
